# why is the following a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Which one of the following subsets of $P_3(F)$ is a vector space?

(A) $\{p: p(1) = 0\}$
(B) $\{p: p(0)p(1) = 0\}$
(C) $\{p: p~~ \text{is monic}\}$
(D) $\{p: p(0) = 1\}$
(E) $\{p(z)=a + bz + cz^2 + dz^3: a,b,c,d\}$

Answer is **A**, but just wondering why this is? Wouldn't this be all the polynomials of the form $x^0$? Also, why are only lines and planes through the origin considered vector spaces? 
Why is $xyz=0$ not a vector space?

Comment: I suppose $P_{3}(F)$ is polynomials of degree 3 over $F$?

Answer (score 2):

Options (B), (C) and (D) are incorrect because corresponding sets of polynomials are not closed under addition.
I am not sure what is wrong with (E), but I think you might have a typo because there are no conditions specified for $\,a,\,b,\,c,\,d.\,$
At the same time, the set of polynomials defined in answer (A) satisfies all conditions of vector (sub-) space.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the axioms? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Introduction_and_definition

Lines and planes that dont include the origin does not contain an additive identity for instane and hence does not meet the axioms. Try going down the list on the rest of your examples.

Comment: @user289419 Plug x=1 into x^0, what do you get? Plug x=1 into x-1, what do you get?

Comment: Think of funamental theoreom of algebra, it means that 1 is a root i.e if we factor it one factor is (x-1).

Comment: the fundamental theorem of algebra is not relevant here, @User2313

Comment: @anon I mean "the factor theorem" sorry.

Comment: @anon Oh right I completely overlooked that one. Thanks heaps

Comment: @user289419 You overlooked all of them. Also, 1^0 is not 0.

Comment: @anon Wait isn't $x^2$-1 also in the subset of p(1)=0.?That is not a vector space though.

Comment: @user289419 Yes $x^2-1$ is a polynomial such that $p(1)=0$. Yes, the set of polynomials satisfying $p(1)=0$ **is** a subspace. All you have to do is check the axioms, it doesn't take more than a minute.

Comment: Maybe I'm phrasing it wrong but what I mean is that if $x^2$-1 is part of the p(1)=0 subset,and since $x^2$-1 fails the T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b) test then how can p(1)=0 be a vector space?